# Getting socket timeout when receiving frequent requests at once

Tags: android, sockets, timeout, touch

I attempting to build a remote controller for my laptop using my phone.
I written a server application that running on my laptop, the remote app used as a client to the server application.
I want to implement a mouse pad, the problem is when I am moving my finger over the "touch pad" too fast, I am receiving read time out on server side after few iterations.

> Server code
>   final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

```
    Runnable serverTask = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
            try
            {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(DEFAULT_PORT);
                serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                _working = true;
                while (_working)
                {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
                    clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Unable to process client request");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    if (serverSocket != null)
                    {
                        serverSocket.close();
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    serverThread.start();

private class ClientTask implements Runnable
{
    private final Socket    clientSocket;

    private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket)
    {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Got a client !");
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Connected!");
            DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

            String request = dIn.readUTF();
            parseRequest(request);
            System.out.println("request=" + request);

            dOut.writeUTF("Got the command");
            dOut.flush(); // Send off the data

            dIn.close();
            dOut.close();

            clientSocket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I thought maybe I will send the requests only if the distance from the starting position to end position is bigger than STEPS(a constant) and only then send the request. But I think the mouse won`t move fluidly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

RXAndroid and RXJava are perfect for asynchronously handling these request and will allow you to add a debounce to the frequent requests. Check out Reactive.io

Comment: Do I need also use RXAndroid or just RXJava, also can you explain how this libs will help me with my problem?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3D0cWyNno4   this video does a good job of explaining the way you can use these libraries in for this purpose. you should use both to make it easier